# Change background-color of drop-down when it is in focus and when it is selected

Tags: html, css

In my form, I have multiple fields, 2 input boxes, and one dropdown. When I press tab I move to the next field until I reach the dropdown. When my tab index reaches the drop-down I want it to be yellow, but as soon as I click on the dropdown it should become a white background. How can I do that?

```css
select:focus{
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

select:hover{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You could make it required and use a `:valid` pseudoselector.

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/4ta4rL8w/)?

Comment: Close, looks like tabbing to the dropdown makes it yellow, that is right. but, When I click on the drop-down I want it to become white background again. @TricksfortheWeb

Comment: would you prefer when the cursor (hover) is on current menu, item it is also white? and also when you click on the menu it is white? or ONLY when you click on the menu?

Comment: maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/anav2avv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some light JavaScript to pull this off, but this ought to get you started:

CSS

```
    .form-row {
      padding: 8px;
    }

    /* when the select is focused, change the bg color */
    select:focus {
      background: yellow
    }
```

Demo Markup:

```
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="text">
        Write Something:
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="select">
        Choose Something:
      </label>

      <select id="select">
        <option>
          opt 1
        </option>
        <option>
          opt 2
        </option>
        <option>
          opt 3
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script>
      // since clicking a select also focuses it, we need to undo
      // the focus style. here i'm adding an inline style to do this
      // but you could add a class that overwrites the focus style instead
      document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.style.background = '#fff'
      });

      // we want to be able to get the yellow focus again
      // if we leave the select box, but re-focus it again
      // so remove the inline style on blur
      document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('blur', function () {
        this.removeAttribute('style');
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thank you all for your help!